# Accessing R.java from different packages

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I have an application divided in subpackages, just for personal organization:

```
com.myname.myapp
 |
 `-  com.myname.myapp.activities
 |
 `-  com.myname.myapp.whatever
 |
 `-  ...
```

The problem is that the generated R.java is located at `com.myname.myapp` and thus when I type `R.id.something` in a class from the subpackage `com.myname.myapp.activities`, I get `R cannot be resolved to a variable` (obvious I guess).

When I click on *Organize imports* (Ctrl+Shift+O), Eclipse fixes it adding `import com.myname.myapp.R` at the top, and everything seems to work perfectly. But on the other hand, [Android documentation](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) states this:

> Eclipse sometimes likes to add an import android.R statement at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete them

Knowing that everything is working perfectly, what should I do?

Comment: If it works, don't fix it. But what is it that you are doing? I'm using packages without having any kind of problems with the R file.

Comment: @Nallath Hmm. Are you using the same setup as me? Can you access the R class from the subpackages without any kind of import or full naming? (i.e. **com.myname.myapp.R**)

Comment: I read this statement to warn from the **exact** statement `import android.R;`, which would import the [Android class `android.R`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html) instead of the app-specific `com.myname.myapp.R`. Doing an import for that `R` class should be fine.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Hm, that makes sense. Then I guess I was doing the right thing, but was just confused by the docs. Thanks!

Comment: You helped me solve this issue just by posting this question. Now it seems so obvious, but I've lost a good couple hours fighting this. Thanx!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can import R.file where ever you want.

```
import com.myname.myapp.R;
```

or else use at the variable like this

```
com.myname.myapp.R.id.test
```

Answer (score 22):

**R.java** is always created at the location(package) mentioned by you in the manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.myname.myapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
```

For any other location or package , you must import R.java file  from the root location.

Hope you understood the issue.

Comment: this is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

The warning has bearance on the fact, there are two versions of the R class. There is a generic version that comes as part of the android packages (android.R) and there is the project specific one that represents your local resource files (com.myname.myapp.R). 
  Just see them as you would the two versions of the Date classes in the java standard library.(java.util.Date & java.sql.Date) two classes, with the same name, specified by package.