# Sub folder yields "Package R does not exist"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Using `Android Studio`. I have one single app Project. `com.myapp.app`. In this project, I have a sub folder `sub` - implying a new namespace: `com.myapp.app.sub`

In this sub folder, all references to `R.string.some_string` produce the following error:

> package R does not exist

How can I make my sub folders aware of the auto-generated `R.java` file?

Comment: Make sure R actually exists. Try cleaning the project and rebuilding. Also make sure you're not importing Android.R

Comment: Checked. This did the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186763/accessing-r-java-from-different-packages Is that the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick: [Accessing R.java from different packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186763/accessing-r-java-from-different-packages)

Not sure if this is the best solution though.